# Why _isAllowed() is being ignored?

Tags: magento-2.1, adminhtml

I'm following the MagentoU course of basic development(full of errors...) and in some point I must create a controller that allows acces only if the GET parameter ***secret*** is set.

I configure the **etc/adminhtml/routes.xml** as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="test" frontName="test">
            <module name="Training_Test" before="Magento_Adminhtml" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

And then make the controller **Controller\Adminhtml\Action\Index.php**

```
<?php
namespace Training\Test\Controller\Adminhtml\Action;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    public function execute()
    {
        $content = $this->getRequest()->getParam('content');
        $this->getResponse()->appendBody($content);
    }

    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        $secret = $this->getRequest()->getParam('secret');
        return isset($secret);
    }
}
```

The thing is, when I call the controller with **base_url/admin/test/action/index/content/hello** it prints ***hello*** on the screen without check the ***_isAllowed()*** function.

I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Admin controller should extend from **\Magento\Backend\App\Action**.
So replace your code following code

```
namespace Training\Test\Controller\Adminhtml\Action;

class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    public function execute()
    {
        $content = $this->getRequest()->getParam('content');
        $this->getResponse()->appendBody($content);
    }

    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        $secret = $this->getRequest()->getParam('secret');
        return isset($secret);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast response Sohel. But with this change now ins't printing anything, it redirects me to the dashboard (even with the param secret in the url).

Comment: Right, So you need to create a menu for it OR Stores -> Configuration -> ADVANCED -> Admin -> Security -> Add Secret Key to URLs set no